# How to check a substring in dataframe included in a long string variable?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, contains

My question is a different way as we usually check string by using `str.contains()`. I want to check if a substring in the dataframe is contained in a long string variable.

The dataframe looks like this:

| Account | Substring | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Cash Payment | Category #1 |
| 1002 | Credit Card Payment | Category #2 |

The long string variable is `long_str = “Cash Payment by Customer”`.

So when using `.loc` to search/filter records in dataframe tha the substring that is contained in the long_str, is there any similar function like `str.contains()` but in the opposite way?

Below is the code I want to try to filter the dataframe, except `str.contains()` that won’t work. Thanks!

`df.loc[df[‘Substring’].str.contains(long_str)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use **`pandas.Series.apply`** method for that:

```
>>> long_str = "Cash Payment by Customer"
>>> df.loc[df.Substring.apply(lambda x: x in long_str)]
   Account     Substring     Category
0     1001  Cash Payment  Category #1
```

Comment: Hi @ank, thank you so much ! This is working..i didn’t really we can use the apply function within the .loc[]. The only problem from that is the performance when we have millions of records to search, wondering if there will be any better solution with better performance? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @XavierSun . Not aware of any better solution for this. However a faster solution could be to use list comprehension directly instead of using the `apply` method. Give this a try and check the performance:  `df.loc[[x in long_str if x is not None else False for x in df.Substring]]`